# How do I download PDF file?

Tags: pdf, books, macos

I am doing web-browsing with Safari on my iphone, and I have opened up a pdf.
How do I save the pdf on the iphone? What if I don't want to save it as "ibook"?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to save it as "ibook" first. And then email your PDFs in iBooks. Last, you can sign in to the email on your computer and download the PDFs. 
[image]